# How to use BlockUI with treetable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, blockui

I am working with `javaEE`, and for my project i used `TreeTable` and `BlockUI` to block this table, but i want to make a button appear even if it is blocked

```
<p:blockUI block=":form:treeTable" widgetVar="tbd" blocked="#{ManagedBean.condition}" />
<h:form id="form">
<p:treeTable id="treeTable" ... >
<f:facet name="header">                    
<p:commandButton value="SomeAction"  actionListener="#{ManagedBean.someAction}" update=":form"/>
</f:facet>
```

in my example i want to make my `commanbutton` appear as available even if i use BlockUI 
thantk you

Comment: Please state your PF version

Comment: i am using `Primefaces 5.2`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a functional problem but a design problem.

As is, the *CommandButton* **is part** of the *TreeTable*, so the *CommandButton* **must be blocked** if the *TreeTable* is blocked.

For sure [Raziels answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38890723/3736575) will work, but a clean solution would be to move the button out of the TreeTable.

```xml
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandButton
        value="SomeAction"
        actionListener="#{ManagedBean.someAction}"
        update=":form"
    />
    <p:treeTable
        id="treeTable"
        ...
    />
    <p:blockUI
        block=":form:treeTable"
        widgetVar="tbd"
        blocked="#{ManagedBean.condition}"
    />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I already Solved this problem by using `z-index:99999` inside a style tag

so your code should be like :

```
<p:blockUI block=":form:treeTable" widgetVar="tbd" blocked="#   {ManagedBean.condition}" />
<h:form id="form">
<p:treeTable id="treeTable" ... >
<f:facet name="header">                    
<p:commandButton value="SomeAction" style="z-index: 99999" actionListener="#{ManagedBean.someAction}" update=":form"/>
</f:facet>
```